# How does this Greatest Common Divisor algorithm work?

Tags: c, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I've just found online this snippet of code that calculates the Greatest Common Divisor of 2 numbers. How does it work?

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    while(b) b ^= a ^= b ^= a %= b;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Edited, now should be more clear

Comment: let's say `a` is 10 `b` is 20, mathematically `gcd(a,b)` should be 10. `a %= b;` gives you remainder of both and that remainder you are storing into `a` by swapping `a` and `b` and rotating loop until `b` not reaches zero, when `b` becomes `0`, `a` is nothing but `gcd(a,b);`

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsequenced non-readonly access to scalar objects.

Comment: News: code-golf cart runs into the UB hole.  Also fails for negative `a,b`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm is what they intend after the modulo operation.

Answer (score 6):

First, I don't believe this is actually correct C, because the same variables are being updated more than once in a single statement without an intervening sequence point.  A simpler example would be:

```
a += ++a;
```

Whether the `a` on the left side of the outer assignment picks up the original or modified `a` is undefined (there's no sequence point within the statement).

That having been said, the intent of the loop body appears to be:

```
a %= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
a %= b;
t = b;
b = a;
a = t;
```

In other words, it sets `a` to `a % b`, then swaps `a` and `b`.

The swapping with the `^` operator works by first setting `b` to `a ^ b`, then xor-ing `a` with that value to get the original `b`, then xor-ing the new `b` (which is `a ^ b`) with the original `b` to get the original `a`.  It's just a convoluted way to swap `a` and `b` without using a temporary variable.

The algorithm itself is just subtracting as many multiples of one from the other as possible, then switching the two numbers, continuing until one of them is zero, at which point the other will contain the GCD (this is based on the Euclidean algorithm).

You can avoid the swapping altogether by unrolling the loop:

```
for (;;) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    a %= b;
    if (a == 0) return b;
    b %= a;
}
```

Comment: UV for "avoid the swapping altogether by unrolling the loop", the better way to do this.

Comment: I concur that the behavior of the code is undefined, including under C2011's sequencing rules, which do not rely exclusively on sequence points.  This much of the key expression has well-defined behavior in C2011: `b ^= a %= b`.

Answer (score 1):

This is using Euclid's algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor, as well as using a trick with xor to swap two variables.

Euclid's algorithm works by first taking `a mod b` then swapping `a` and `b`, repeating until one of them is 0.  Then the other is the result.  You can read more about it on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

The xor trick for swapping the two variables is just used to avoid using a temporary variable.  You can read more about why this works on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).  Let me illustrate an example for you so you can see how this would work.

```
int a = 0b1100;
int b = 0b1010;

a = a ^ b;  // 1100 ^ 1010 = 0110
b = a ^ b;  // 0110 ^ 1010 = 1100
a = a ^ b;  // 0110 ^ 1100 = 1010
// Now a and b are swapped.
```